# Flutter Autocomplete widget delays updating suggestions

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I'm facing a problem using the Autocomplete widget. Basically, the list of options that shows up while I'm typing in the text field is delayed by one character.

For example, let's say a set of data like ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]. If the text field is initially empty and I start typing the letter 'A', nothing happens. Then I type for example the letter 'k', so that there shouldn't be any match with data, but the widget displays "Apple" in the options list. Then let's say I remove the last letter, 'k', so that there is only the 'A' and there should be a match with the word "Apple", but the widget doesn't display anything. And so on.

```
Autocomplete<Song>(
      optionsBuilder: (_) => state.searchResults,
      fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
        return TextField(
          controller: controller,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          onChanged: (value) {
            context.read(searchProvider.notifier).inputChanged(value);
          },
        );
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Material(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding / 3),
                itemExtent: 40.0,
                children: options
                    .map(
                      (song) => SuggestionEntry(song: song),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

I'm using Riverpod as state manager, but it shouldn't be the problem since I'm using the same StateNotifier also in other parts of the page which are updated correctly. Also, note that the list of suggestions stored in the StateNotifier is correctly based on the current input, so it seems that the problem is during the "rendering" of the Autocomplete widget.

Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17FZuxgDoHhOR2ceAUsOtADZZe23BU0m1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having issues with riverpod autodispose

Comment: Can you show the function definition for state.searchResults?

Answer (score 2):

`optionsBuilder` is called before `fieldViewBuilder.onChange`.
So remove the part

```
onChanged: (value) {
    context.read(searchProvider.notifier).inputChanged(value);
},
```

and move the definition to inside `optionsBuilder` like:

```
optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue value) {
    await context.read(searchProvider.notifier).inputChanged(value);
    return ...;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of options, you need to pass state.searchResults

````
Autocomplete<Song>(
      optionsBuilder: (_) => state.searchResults,
      fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
        return TextField(
          controller: controller,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          onChanged: (value) {
            context.read(searchProvider.notifier).inputChanged(value);
          },
        );
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Material(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 100.0,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding / 3),
                itemExtent: 40.0,
                children: state.searchResults
                    .map(
                      (song) => SuggestionEntry(song: song),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
    ```
````